# ASP.NET Core MVC paging binding

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to add paging to my table in ASP.NET Core MVC.

**Issue:** how can I link `TotalRecords`, `PageNo`, & `PageSize` from controller to the view? In Razor page its simple to bind them, but I don't know how to do this in MVC.

```
TotalRecords = Query.AsQueryable().Count(); 
PageNo = p; 
PageSize = s;
```

Controller:

```
    // Display Data
    public async Task<IActionResult> DisplayData(int p = 1, int s = 20)
    {
        try
        {
            IQueryable<MyModel> query = await _services.GetData();

            // Add Paging
            query = await AddPaging(p, s, query);

            // Display Data
            List<MyModel> myData = await query.AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();
            
            return View(myData);   // return view with data 
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();     // return empty view
        } 
    }

    // add paging
    private async Task<IQueryable<MyModel>> AddPaging(int p, int s, IQueryable<MyModel> Query)
    {
        TotalRecords = Query.AsQueryable().Count(); 
        PageNo = p; 
        PageSize = s;  
        Query = Query.Skip((p - 1) * s).Take(s);
        return Query;
    }    // end of paging
```

View:

```
@model List<MyModel>
<table>
  ....
</table>

<paging total-records="Model.TotalRecords"
    page-no="Model.PageNo"
    show-prev-next="false"
    show-first-last="false">
</paging>
```

Comment: Do you mean the model in `paging` tag can't bind the value from controller?

Comment: [This nuget](https://docs.ziyad.info/en/LazZiya.TagHelpers/v6.0/index.md) could help to build a paging navigation easily.

Comment: @XinranShen values of paging I need to set from controller. ex:  `Model.TotalRecords`

Comment: @LazZiya thanks, that plugin is easy to set up in razor page bc of binding. Do you know if this also works in MVC? i am new to MVC and wasn't sure how to set `Model.TotalRecords` values from the controller

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to solve this  problem with OOP standards.

First make a class that will do pagination.

Example:

```
    public class Paginate<T>
    {
        public Paginate(List<T> datas, int currentPage, int totalPage)
        {
            Datas = datas;
            CurrentPage = currentPage;
            TotalPage = totalPage;

        }
        public List<T> Datas { get; set; }
        public int CurrentPage { get; set; }
        public int TotalPage { get; set; }
        public bool HasPrev
        {
            get
            {
                return CurrentPage > 1;
            }
        }
        public bool HasNext
        {
            get
            {
                return CurrentPage < TotalPage;
            }
        }

    }
```

Then send data to view by this class.

```
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index(int page = 1, int take = 5)
        {
            var datas = await _context.Datas
                .Skip((page - 1) * take)
                .Take(take)
                .AsNoTracking()                    
                .ToListAsync();
            
        int dataCount = await _context.Datas.CountAsync();
        int initCount = (int)Math.Ceiling((decimal)count / take);

            Paginate<Categories> result = new Paginate<Datas>(datas , page, initCount );

            return View(result);
        }
```

Last step is sending initial datas to controller from view.

First your view will take data from pagination class.

```
@model Paginate<List<MyModel>>
```

Then your pagination component will send data to controller:

```
             <ul>
                <li class="@(Model.HasPrev?"":"disabled")">
                    <a asp-action="Index" asp-route-page="@(Model.CurrentPage-1)">Previous</a>
                </li>
                @for (int i = 1; i <= Model.TotalPage; i++)
                {
                    <li class="@(i==Model.CurrentPage ? "disabled":"")">
                        <a asp-action="Index" asp-route-page="@i">@i</a>
                    </li>
                }


                <li class="@(Model.HasNext?"":"disabled")">
                    <a asp-action="Index" asp-route-page="@(Model.CurrentPage+1)">Next</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
```

If you analize all code I think it will be useful. Or you can take the business logic and apply it to your `DisplayData` and `AddPaging` methods.